# Ruby 2.0 Bytecode Export / Import

Tags: ruby, bytecode, yarv, ruby-2.0

I've been reading about the [new ruby 2.0 features](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-2-0-implementation-work-begins-what-is-ruby-2-0-and-whats-new-5515.html), and found that it will support bytecode import / export:

> Ruby 2.0 is expected to make it simple to save pre-compiled Ruby scripts to bytecode representations and to then run these directly.

I've installed ruby-2.0.0-p0, but I didn't find any information on how to export the bytecode (or generally documentation on that matter). Is this feature already implemented, and if so, how do I use it?

I'm also wondering about some of the details. Is YARV-bytecode supposed to be platform-independent? Are all gems automatically included in the bytecode?

Answer (score 5):

Until someone with better information looks at this question, I did some research:

> Is this feature already implemented, and if so, how do I use it?

It is implemented, but it doesn't seem to be exposed (e.g `ruby --dump-bytecode` doesn't exist).  Also there's not very much [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html).  As far as I can tell, what you are looking for is something like:

```
seq = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_file("./example.rb")
```

`seq.disassemble` will give you a nicely formatted string that you could dump to a file, or `seq.to_a` will generate an an array that looks like:

```
["YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat",
 2,
 0,
 1,
 {:arg_size=>0, :local_size=>1, :stack_max=>2},
 "<main>",
 "./example.rb",
 "./example.rb",
 1,
 :top,
 [],
 0,
 [],
 [[:trace, 1],
  [:putspecialobject, 3],
  [:putnil],
  [:defineclass,
   :User,
   ["YARVInstructionSequence/SimpleDataFormat",
    2,
    0,
    1,
    {:arg_size=>0, :local_size=>1, :stack_max=>6},
    "<class:User>",
    ....
```

If you want to persist this to a file, you can do something like:

```
File.write("out.dump", Marshal.dump(seq.to_a))
```

And then to load again:

```
arr = Marshal.load(File.read("out.dump"))
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to create a new `InstructionSequence` given the array loaded above.

> I'm also wondering about some of the details. Is YARV-bytecode supposed to be platform-independent? Are all gems automatically included in the bytecode?

In the example above, gems are not included.  Your `InstructionSequence` would include the bytecode equivalent of a `require 'active_record'` or what have you.  I suspect that if dumping and loading of bytecode were provided directly by a `ruby` executable, this behavior would stay the same.

If anyone else has more information I'd love to see it!

Comment: Is `RubyVM::InstructionSequence` really new in 2.0? See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html. I also would've expected some flags for the main ruby executable.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it looks like the verifier didn't get implemented in 2.0-p0, and as a result the load functionality is still commented out (from iseq.c, line 2260):

```
/* disable this feature because there is no verifier. */
/* rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cISeq, "load", iseq_s_load, -1); */
```