# Compiling Ruby 2.1 to bytecode

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

While [Ruby 1.9 was compiling to bytecode](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136883#610331), it could not save a pre-compiled script to disk.

We were told to expect [Ruby 2 to allow saving compiled bytecode](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-2-0-implementation-work-begins-what-is-ruby-2-0-and-whats-new-5515.html) to disk, but I haven't heard much talk of that, or seen bazillions of blog posts describing how to gain performance through compilation, which I would expect to see if it were in fact implemented somewhere in Ruby 2.x.

A [focused Google search](http://www.google.com/cse?q=compile&cx=013598269713424429640%3Ag5orptiw95w&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=compile&gsc.page=1) doesn't seem to return anything useful.

Is it possible in 2.1 (or earlier)?  If not, is this still on the roadmap?

Comment: It'd make more sense to ask this on the Ruby-talk mail-list, or the Ruby IRC channel on Freenode. That's where the real people that know hang out.

Comment: yeah I'd re-ask on ruby-dev (I thought I remember seeing something about it.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398964/ruby-2-0-bytecode-export-import and https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136883#610331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any work in this direction from reading ruby-core (I am a committer).  Compilation to bytecode doesn't take very long in ruby.  Compared to the runtime of most ruby programs it hasn't yet made sense to persist compiled bytecode to disk.

Answer (score 5):

#### It's half-possible.

- Download extension from [here](https://github.com/wanabe/iseq) and compile it.
- Require lib `iseq.so`
- ok, now `load` method for bytecode available

#### Example (compilator/loader)

```rb
require "zlib"
require "./ext/iseq" # ./ext/iseq.so

# ARGV[0] compile or load
# ARGV[1] file to compile or load

case ARGV[0]
when 'compile'
  File.open("#{File.basename(ARGV[1],'.rb')}.bin",'w') do |f|
    f << Zlib::Deflate.deflate(
      Marshal.dump(
        ISeq.compile_file( ARGV[1] ).to_a
        )
    )
  end
when 'load'
  ( File.open( ARGV[1], 'r') do |f|
      ISeq.load(
        Marshal.restore(
          Zlib::Inflate.inflate( f.read )
        )
      )
    end ).eval
else
  puts 'need options'
end
```

#### it's usage

```
$ ruby compilator.rb compile my_project.rb # => compile to bytecode
$ ruby compilator.rb load my_project.bin   # => load from bytecode and eval
```

#### Note

For simplest project it's works on the same ruby interpreeter (1.9.3 and 2.x.x are incompatible). But for slightly more complicated project it doesn't work (segmentation fault).